# How to enable wp_wcm_async theme module in WebSphere Portal 8.5 CF 06 theme?

Tags: websphere-portal

Recently, I have applied Fix Pack CF06 to my WebSphere Portal 8.5.

This fix pack provide new feature of asynchronously loading the content in Web Content Manager Portlet. For information [Click Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJ99_8.5.0/wcm/wcm_config_asynch_wcm_rendr.html)

I have successfully completed step 1, skip step 2 because I don't want to change the loading mask. But I am not able to complete step 3, because I don't know how to enable `wp_wcm_theme` module in my customized theme. The `wp_wcm_theme` javascript object is always undefined for my Page.

I have also tried with applying **Portal 8.5** Theme, but that also don't work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable wp_wcm_async module in your theme. Open the themelist using WebDav or other client. Move into your theme folder -> **profiles**. In each and every profile or in the necessary profile add the "**wp_wcm_async**" inside "moduleIDs" json.

For example :

```
modeleIDs : {
    "wp_theme_portal_85",
    "wp_toolbar_host",
    "some other modules",
    "wp_wcm_async"
}
```

Save the file and restart the portal server, now you can access the `wp_wcm_async` theme module inside your theme which gives you access to `wp_wcm_async` global java script object.